# iPhone not displaying background images correctly

Tags: iphone, css, background-image

I've just built a site with four content blocks sitting ontop of one another to create a longish page.

Each block is the full width of the screen and the height of the screen and has a background image.

Now when the site loads it shows the first block and the background image displays correctly. When the user scrolls to the second block the background image does not display until the majority of the block is in the viewport then it will load.

Does anyone know why this would be the case, is it an iOS issue?

Comment: Please share your code. We cannot help without it. Try putting together a jsFiddle demo too.

Comment: Sorry here you go http://jsfiddle.net/ZdhCK/

Comment: Have you tried playing progressive and non-progressive JPG images?

Comment: Hi Steve I have. It's not that as the image will display fully when it scrolls into the second block

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the "fixed" from the background declaration, it will work as you want it to.